# Global logger for logging without a node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far, all the examples I've seen for logging involves  using the `get_logger()` method of `rclcpp::Node`, e.g.

```
RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "my_message");
```

Is there a global logger that is can be used for logging without having access to a node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355985/global-logger-for-logging-without-a-node/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-06-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out loggers can be created on the fly with [`rclcpp::get_logger`](https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Logger.html#a065ae21b8b626fa98be4ad3ce03fb070) for your logging purposes.  e.g.

```
RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("my_logger"), "my_message");
```

Also, remember to set [the following](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Logging-and-logger-configuration/#line-buffered-console-output) if you're not seeing any log outputs (took me way too long to figure it out...)

```
export RCUTILS_CONSOLE_STDOUT_LINE_BUFFERED=1
```

In newer ROS versions, it should be

```
export RCUTILS_LOGGING_USE_STDOUT=1 && export RCUTILS_LOGGING_BUFFERED_STREAM=1
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) on 2022-01-18**:
Does someone have an answer for rclpy?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In response to @tnajjar, to do this in Python, use [RcutilsLogger](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/humble/rclpy/rclpy/impl/rcutils_logger.py#L214) under `rclpy.impl`

```
from rclpy.impl import rcutils_logger
logger = rcutils_logger.RcutilsLogger(name="my_logger")
logger.info("Hello World")
```

You will see something like

```
[INFO] [1681758901.959964134] [my_logger]: Hello World
```

[Underneath the hood](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/humble/rclpy/rclpy/impl/rcutils_logger.py#L318), some function from [rcutils](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils) is called that does the job of logging.

---

Originally posted by [zkytony](https://answers.ros.org/users/26716/zkytony/) with karma: 178 on 2023-04-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) on 2023-04-17**:
Thank you, I'll definitely try it out